# Multiple inner joins mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing an sql statement in which I have multiple `INNER JOIN` statements with a final `WHERE` clause. I have achieved this using the following query:

```sql
select weapon_name 
  from special_weapons
     , player
     , player_weapons 
 where player.uuid = player_weapons.uuid 
   and player_weapons.weaponid = special_weapons.weaponid;
```

However, this inner join syntax is considered bad practice. I have tried rewriting this query *numerous* times and continually run into a gambit of problems. I attempted the following, all of which failed:

```sql
SELECT sp1.WEAPON_NAME 
        FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS sp1, PLAYER_WEAPONS pw 
    INNER JOIN PLAYER p1 ON 
        pw.UUID = p1.uuid 
    INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw1 ON 
        sp1.weaponid = pw1.weapondid;
```

> *ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sp1.weaponid' in 'on clause*

Attempt 2:

```sql
SELECT WEAPON_NAME 
  FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS, PLAYER_WEAPONS 
 INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER_WEAPONS.UUID = PLAYER.UUID 
 INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS ON SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID = 
    PLAYER_WEAPONS.WEAPONID;
```

> *ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'PLAYER_WEAPONS'*

Attempt 3:

```sql
SELECT WEAPON_NAME 
  FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS, PLAYER_WEAPONS 
INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER_WEAPONS.UUID = PLAYER.UUID 
INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw ON SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID = pw.WEAPONID;
```

> *ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID' in 'on clause'*

My tables look as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT weapon_name
FROM player p
JOIN player_weapons pw ON p.uuid = pw.uuid
JOIN special_weapons sw ON pw.weaponid = sw.weaponid
```

there is no magic stuff behind this query. I just rewrite it using your original successful query. you had a hard time probably because the table order in the query.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You write that *this inner join syntax is considered bad practice.* This is true partially - comma-separated tables join is CROSS JOIN, not INNER (but in MySQL they're synonims - MySQL extension allows any JOIN type clause without ON clause rather than another DBMSs which allows this for CROSS JOIN only). The words *bad practice* are correct 100%.

But then you try to use the mix of comma-separated join and INNER join - this is not bad but extremely bad practice.

---

And detailed:

Attempt1.

```
SELECT sp1.WEAPON_NAME 
        FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS sp1, PLAYER_WEAPONS pw 
    INNER JOIN PLAYER p1 ON 
        pw.UUID = p1.uuid 
    INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw1 ON 
        sp1.weaponid = pw1.weapondid;
```

means

```
SELECT sp1.WEAPON_NAME 
FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS sp1, (            PLAYER_WEAPONS pw 
                            INNER JOIN PLAYER p1 ON pw.UUID = p1.uuid 
                            INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw1 ON sp1.weaponid = pw1.weapondid 
                          );
```

`sp1` alias is not accessible within the parenthesis because this alias is defined out of them.

---

Attempt 2.

```
SELECT WEAPON_NAME 
  FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS, PLAYER_WEAPONS                    -- first PLAYER_WEAPONS
 INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER_WEAPONS.UUID = PLAYER.UUID 
 INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS ON SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID =  -- second PLAYER_WEAPONS
    PLAYER_WEAPONS.WEAPONID;
```

---

Attempt 3.

```
SELECT WEAPON_NAME 
  FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS, PLAYER_WEAPONS 
INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER_WEAPONS.UUID = PLAYER.UUID 
INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw ON SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID = pw.WEAPONID;
```

means

```
SELECT WEAPON_NAME 
  FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS, (            PLAYER_WEAPONS 
                          INNER JOIN PLAYER ON PLAYER_WEAPONS.UUID = PLAYER.UUID 
                          INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS pw ON SPECIAL_WEAPONS.WEAPONID = pw.WEAPONID
                        );
```

Non-aliased `SPECIAL_WEAPONS` table copy is not accessible within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SW.WEAPON_NAME FROM SPECIAL_WEAPONS SW 
INNER JOIN PLAYER_WEAPONS PW ON PW.WEAPONID = SW.WEAPONID 
INNER JOIN PLAYER P ON P.UUID = PW.UUID;
```

you can use the WHERE clause to get output of three table join.